# iOS app times out on error instead of processing it

Tags: ios, restkit

In the RestKit app I'm making the requests and responses are working happily, but now I'm trying to add error handling. I'm following the example in the [RestKit readme](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit#centralize-configuration-in-an-object-manager) and similar examples from the net, but run into some strange behaviour.

The error mapping is added with

```
// Error JSON looks like {"errors": "Some Error Has Occurred"}
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
// The entire value at the source key path containing the errors maps to the message
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError);
// Any response in the 4xx status code range with an "errors" key path uses this mapping
RKResponseDescriptor *errorDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"errors" statusCodes:statusCodes];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:errorDescriptor];
```

When I make my service simulate an error instead of returning data, the following happens. The response of my service is

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Tue, 26 May 2015 19:01:21 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Connection: Close

{"errors":"This is a test exception"}
```

after which the connection is closed. On the client side, however, the failure block of `getObjectsAtPath:` isn't executed immediately. Instead the function waits for a timeout and doesn't return an error object. The error is **[Updated. Replaced with log including trace logging]**:

```
2015-05-27 14:08:25.968 Olive Oil[37455:37884261] I restkit:RKLog.m:49 RestKit logging initialized...
2015-05-27 14:08:26.275 Olive Oil[37455:37884261] 320.000000
2015-05-27 14:08:26.415 Olive Oil[37455:37884261] T restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:148 GET 'http://192.168.69.88/OliveOil.svc/recipies':
request.headers={
    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";
    Authorization = "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXX==";
    "User-Agent" = "Olive Oil/1 (iPad Simulator; iOS 8.3; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body=(null)
2015-05-27 14:09:33.559 Olive Oil[37455:37885022] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:544 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7f91f36ad440 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f91f37271e0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.69.88/OliveOil.svc/recipies, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.69.88/OliveOil.svc/recipies, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
2015-05-27 14:09:33.559 Olive Oil[37455:37885022] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:209 GET 'http://192.168.69.88/OliveOil.svc/recipies' (401 Unauthorized / 0 objects) [request=67.1418s mapping=0.0000s total=67.2429s]:error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x7f91f36ad440 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f91f37271e0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.69.88/OliveOil.svc/recipies, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.69.88/OliveOil.svc/recipies, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
2015-05-27 14:09:33.560 Olive Oil[37455:37885022] D restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:210 response.body=(null)
```

So apparently the status 401 gets communicated (2nd error), but something makes the RestKit wait for more data. What could be the cause of this behaviour? Some misconfiguration? Is the service response malformed? Is there something wrong with the error mapping?

Comment: Could really do with more log. Are you sure only 1 request was in progress?

Comment: This is what happens. The request is sent. The service replies with the error. And after a period of waiting the timeout happens. There's nothing in between.

And yes... I'm absolutely sure there was only one request. It's the initial request and only after it's been processed, additional requests are send.

Comment: Haven't seen a result like yours before. Turn on trace logging for network and see what extra info it provides. Does this only happen when you have the error mapping code included?

Comment: I've included trace logging for network. This is really all that's happening.

This only happens when the error is generated on the service side. But it seems the service itself is acting funny. I have to investigate on that side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the service side, the connection wasn't closed after the data was sent.

After making the appropriate changes, the app processes the error information as expected. Thanks, [Wain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988185/wain), for pointing me in the right direction.